# Matlab: Write table to Excel (using named range)

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel, named-ranges

```
writetable(myTable,'myFile.xlsx','Sheet','Matlab','Range','A2', 'WriteRowNames', 1);
```

It seems that if I replace 'A2' by a Named Range, this function does not work.

```
writetable(myTable,'myFile.xlsx','Sheet','Matlab','Range','myRange', 'WriteRowNames', 1);
```

Returns:

```
  Error using writetable (line 106)
  The range must be a string of the form 'A1:B2' or 'A1'.
```

I tried to define the Named Range in Excel as local and global with same result.
Is there another way to write a table to Excel to a specific names range instead of to an address?

Xlswrite: supports named range but does not support tables

table2array: makes me lose all the column and row names

Comment: `writetable` should work with Named Range according to its help [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html?refresh=true#namevaluepairarguments). Could you elaborate on what you experience when you use Named Range argument?.

Comment: I am using 2014b. Might it be that 2014b did not have this feature yet?